# Eclipse, Java. Move GUI elements with a joystick?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

I'm trying to create a GUI that shows the position of a controller joy stick on screen. i'm thinking of a gray box with a red dot to represent where the stick is at. So far i've been able to take the value of the joy stick and put that into a float variable. ( I Don't fully understand why it has to be a float variable, eclipse gives the error "cannot convert from float to int")

Here's what code i have right now.

```
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Controller;
import org.lwjgl.input.Controllers;

public class Start{

    static Controller controller;
    public static boolean Start;


public static void main(String[]args){

    try {
        Controllers.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        Controllers.poll();

        for(int i=0;i<Controllers.getControllerCount();i++){
            controller=Controllers.getController(i);
            System.out.println(controller.getName());
        }
        controller=Controllers.getController(16);
        for (int i=0;i<controller.getAxisCount();i++){
        System.out.println(i+": "+controller.getAxisName(i));
        }
        for (int i=0;i<controller.getButtonCount();i++){
            System.out.println(i+ ": "+controller.getButtonName(i));
        }
        while(true){
            controller.poll();
            Start=controller.isButtonPressed(0);
                float axis1= controller.getAxisValue(1);
                System.out.println(axis1);

        }
    }
}
```

What can I use for the red dot in the GUI to move with that variable value?

Here's a picture of the controller i'm working with with all the inputs labeled to what they appear as in Eclipse. I am only tracking the left stick's left and right movement. When the stick is all the way to the left the variable is -1 and to the right is 1

[Picture of the controller I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp9rj.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a floating point, because there are no absolute values, because there are no "steps".

Like Left / Center-Left / Center / Center-Right / Right

You will need to do some calculations. Lets say your canvas is a square of 201 pixel.

In this case you could add 1 to the position and multiply with 100

Edge cases:

**Left postion**

-1 + 1  = 0 
0 * 100 = 0

Left pixel at your canvas

**Center position**

0 +   1 =   1
1 * 100 = 100

Middle Pixel

**Right position**

1 + 1   =   2
2 * 100 = 200

Right pixel at your canvas.

Comment: very helpful in terms of the math but my question was more about what method to use. I later figured out that I just had to use the label.setLocation(x,y) to move the dot around.